# "Access is denied" error while trying to build an SMS app in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I'm trying to build an android app which automatically sends an SMS at a given time.
When I try to run it, I get the following error in "Run tasks":

```
app\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_ (Access is denied)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In all my time using android studio, I have never seen this error. My only recommendation is to run a clean build. Also, make sure you requested access to use SMS in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

instead of

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```